# HTML .png blurry

Tags: html, css, image, blur

I'm currently working on a website using a template and when I replaced the background image I noticed that it's blurry. I've read a lot online that it has to do with the `z-index`, but changing that does absolutely nothing for me. This is the code on the html/css file. 
I would be very happy to hear any suggestions towards fixes. Never posted on here before, so just ask whatever you need, if I forgot something

```css
.single-slider {
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    padding: 80px 0;
    position: relative;

}

.single-slider::before {
    background:  none repeat scroll 0 0;
    content: "";
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0.;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

```html
<div class="single-slider" style="background-image:url(img/slider/background-home.png)">
</div>
```

Comment: I tried using "z-index: 1" and "z-index: 99999" and none of them made any difference at all

Comment: Your code snippet shows a blank :) You might want to set some sizes for the demo :)

Comment: can you provide a link to the image, you could put it google drive or drop box and provide a link to the image.

Comment: Hi @Marc, the background-size is in "cover", that's mean that if the container is bigger than the image, it will stretch the image, in other words, the container is full cover by the image and if the container is bigger, the image will be pixelated

Comment: z-index has nothing to do with blurriness. How does the image looks if you open it on your computer? Perhaps it is blurry or just too small. Also check if your image inherits any filter:blur(x) properties

Comment: The .png is exported with 1920 px width, so stretch cant be it

Comment: I also just tested the colours with my colour picker and the colours aren't the same, so there has to be something going on

Comment: #A9BB3E and #12384BB are used on the original exported png, yet on the website the colours are #A9BB47 and #1D85B9

Comment: It's really hard to test without having the image.

Comment: Sadly I cannot upload the img publicly bc of the new GDPR

Comment: @Marc Can you replicate the issue with a different image?

Comment: tried a few different images, different file types, same problem every time. There either has to be a problem within what i posted or somewhere else I can't think of rn

Comment: Okay so I fixed it by removing the stlye from the html and setting the img as background the the css. No idea how that can make such a big difference but seems to have fixed it

Comment: But now the image doesn't scale down for the mobile page anymore ...
New CSS:

Comment: .single-slider {
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    padding: 80px 0;
    position: relative;
    background: url("img/slider/larissa-khodai-home.png") center;

}